# Vue/Vuex: Implicitly pass object to all children

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

I'm doing some analytics work and 'link position' needs to be accessed by a number of child elements. Behold, a contrived example:

```
  <Page>
    <MyComponent linkPosition='TopSection''>
      <SomeThing>
        <MyLink />
      </SomeThing>
    </MyComponent>
    <MyComponent linkPosition='BottomSection''>
      <SomeThing>
        <MyLink />
      </SomeThing>
    </MyComponent>
  </Page>
```

`MyLink` and other assorted components need to grab that `linkPosition` attribute. In real life, these components are in various `<slot>`s and a half-dozen levels deep, so it's a hassle to explicitly pass this down.

We're using Vuex, if that makes a difference.

Comment: If you are using vuex can't you store the linkPosition in the store and then retrieve it in the child components when they are created

Comment: You wouldn't pass it to the children, the children would fetch the data from the store

Comment: The store doesn't really store information about he position of components in the DOM, though, which is what I'd be passing around here.

Comment: Let the child loop through the `$parent`'s till it found the attribute `linkposition`
`if (this.$parent.$parent.linkPosition) {do whatever}`

Comment: One thing is certain. The parent with the attribute `linkPosition` should not know about the children or care how many children there is.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a small recursive function for you which any of the children component can call which goes through the hierarchy of parent to find the parent with certain attribute and return that attribute value to caller. You just need to add additional checks to prevent any deadman loops.

```
export function findParentAttrValue(parent: any, attr: string): string {
  if (parent[`${attr}`]) {
    return parent[`${attr}`];
  } else {
    return findParentAttrValue(parent.$parent, attr);
  }
}
```